# Find text in element that is NOT wrapped in html tags and wrap it with <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, word-wrap

```
<div class="menu-content">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  TEXT THAT NEEDS TO BE WRAPPED
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I got the code above (it gets generated automatically so I can't manually wrap the text), I need to filter through the content of ".menu-content" and find the text that is not wrapped in a html tags and then wrap that text in a p tag.

I tried the following jQuery code:

```
$('.menu-content').find(':not(h3, ul)').wrap('<p></p>');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to get text node

```js
$('.menu-content')
  .contents() // get all child node including text and comment 
  .filter(function() { // filter the text node which is not empty
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent).length
  }).wrap('</p>'); // wrap filtered element with p
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-content">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  TEXT THAT NEEDS TO BE WRAPPED
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: LEGEND! Thanks Mate

Comment: @AJDEV : glad to help :)