# Javascript find unparented text within element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been puzzling over this one for days.

I have a CMS that sometimes doesn't put text inside of a paragraph when it should. I have no control over the produced HTML. Say I have multiple divs on the page that look like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
    Unparented text
    <p>Parented text</p>
    More unparented text
    <p>More parented text</p>
</div>
```

How would I update the div so that each section of unparented text is surrounded in its own `<p>` tag?

Comment: Do you want to change the text or the p tags?

Comment: If you bothered to search, there are already [several answered questions on StackOverflow that addresses your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wrap+textnode).

Comment: I did search extensively, but not with those keywords.

Comment: Explore `.contents()` [https://api.jquery.com/contents/] and extrapolate from there.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506770/find-text-in-element-that-is-not-wrapped-in-html-tags-and-wrap-it-with-p AND: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags